# Move files based on odd number in file name - powershell

Tags: powershell, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to move files with odd numbers at the end of the filename from one folder to another but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried using if statements and for loops no to avail. Some pointers would be much appreciated. My attempts are below..

```
$srcpath = "C:\Folder\SubFolder3"
$dstpath = "C:\Folder\SubFolder2"
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $srcpath |
    ForEach-Object {
        if($_.Name -match '*1.txt', '*3.txt', '*5.txt', '*7.txt', '*9.txt') {
            Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $dstpath
        }
    }
```

```
$srcpath = "C:\Folder\SubFolder3"
$dstpath = "C:\Folder\SubFolder2"
$files = $srcpath
foreach ($file in $files) {
    if ($file -like '*1.txt', '*3.txt', '*5.txt', '*7.txt', '*9.txt') {
        Move-Item -Destination $dstpath
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither `-match` nor `-like` support an array of patterns as the RHS argument. This must be a single regular expression string for `-match` or a single wildcard string for `-like`. For `-match` you can use the RegEx alternation operator `|` to combine multiple patterns: https://regex101.com/r/vDORxi/1 or simpler https://regex101.com/r/mjB0qN/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the `-match` operator only returns true if all the matches are found in the string, not if only one of them is found.

You could try with something like this instead if the filenames only contain one digit. This will fail is there are digits in any other position in the filename.

```
$srcpath = "C:\Folder\SubFolder3"
$dstpath = "C:\Folder\SubFolder2"
Get-ChildItem -File -Recurse -Path $srcpath |
    ForEach-Object {
        # look for a digit
        if($_.Name -match '[\d]') {
            # is that digit odd?
            if([int]($Matches[0]) % 2 -eq 1) {
                Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $dstpath
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't work for file names like `File21.txt`, even though it ends in an odd number (ignoring the extension) - it matches the `2` and stops there (which, obviously, isn't odd).  Change the `if` condition to this to be more accurate: `$_.BaseName -match '\d$'`, or change it to `[13579]$` and remove the modulus test.

Comment: Yes, agree. That's much better, thanks!